# How to create individual consent pages on ResearchKit?

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, xcode7, researchkit

I am using Xcode 7.1.1 coding with ResearchKit on Swift for iPhone iOS 9.1. I am trying to create the consent pages and have been looking online trying to find examples to no success.

From http://www.raywenderlich.com/104575/researchkit-tutorial-with-swift , I have gotten the code:

```
import Foundation
import ResearchKit

public var ConsentDocument:ORKConsentDocument {

let consentDocument=ORKConsentDocument()
consentDocument.title = "Consent"

//Consent Sections
let consentSectionTypes: [ORKConsentSectionType] = [
    .Overview,
    .DataGathering,
    .Privacy,
    .DataUse,
    .TimeCommitment,
    .StudySurvey,
    .StudyTasks,
    .Withdrawing
]
let consentSections: [ORKConsentSection] = consentSectionTypes.map { contentSectionType in
    let consentSection = ORKConsentSection(type: contentSectionType)

    consentSection.summary = "If you wish to complete this study..."
    consentSection.content = "In this study you will only be asked 10 easy question!!!"
    return consentSection
}


consentDocument.sections = consentSections

// Getting Signature
consentDocument.addSignature(ORKConsentSignature(forPersonWithTitle: nil, dateFormatString: nil, identifier: "ConsentDocumentParticipantSignature"))

return consentDocument
}
```

The problem is, this code creates every page with the same summary and content. How can I make an individual page for each individual section??

Comment: You can use a switch block inside the map and assign different strings for different `contentSectionType`.

Comment: @Yuan Can you give an example? I am trying 
''switch consentSectionTypes {
        case consentSectionTypes.Overview:
            Overview.summary = "If you wish to complete this study..."
            Overview.content = "In this study you will only be asked 10 easy question!!!"''

Answer (score 2):

as Yuan suggested replace your map function as follows:

```
 let consentSections: [ORKConsentSection] = consentSectionTypes.map { contentSectionType in
    let consentSection = ORKConsentSection(type: contentSectionType)
    switch contentSectionType {
    case .Overview:
        consentSection.summary = "Overview"
        consentSection.content = "Overview - Content"
    case .DataGathering:
        consentSection.summary = "DataGathering"
        consentSection.content = "DataGathering - Content"
    case .Privacy:
        consentSection.summary = "Privacy"
        consentSection.content = "Privacy - Content"
    case .DataUse:
        consentSection.summary = "DataUse"
        consentSection.content = "DataUse - Content"
    case .TimeCommitment:
        consentSection.summary = "TimeCommitment"
        consentSection.content = "TimeCommitment - Content"
    case .StudySurvey:
        consentSection.summary = "StudySurvey"
        consentSection.content = "StudySurvey - Content"
    case .StudyTasks:
        consentSection.summary = "StudyTasks"
        consentSection.content = "StudyTasks - Content"
    case .Withdrawing:
        consentSection.summary = "Withdrawing"
        consentSection.content = "Withdrawing - Content"
    default:
        break
   }
   return consentSection
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer!